# HTML, onsubmit does not work

Tags: html, onsubmit

I am new to HTML and I face a problem with my code regarding the form onSubmit.

When I do not use the form and have the onSubmit="Move()" in input as onClick="Move", then the function Move works perfectly fine.

However, when I include the form and put onSubmit="Move()" then the function does not work at all.

May someone point out my mistake and provide a solution to this? This really drives me mad.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
</style>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css')}}'>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='/static/style.css'>-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div class=metanav>

            <h4>Please enter a stock ticker eg. GOOG, and check desired features.</h4>

            <form onsubmit="Move()">

                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 

            </form>

            <div id="myProgress">
                  <div id="myBar">10%</div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function Move() {
                    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
                    var width = 10;
                    var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
                    function frame() {
                        if (width >= 100) {
                          clearInterval(id);
                        } else {
                          width++; 
                          elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                          elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        <hr>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the console?

Comment: Your form will be really submitted when you submit it. Since you have not set an action, or canceled the submit, it will reload the current page. You could use: `onsubmit="Move(); return false;"` The false will cancel the submit.

Comment: By default, forms submit back to the server, so the page will refresh. You need to make it `onsubmit="return Move()"` and `return false;` at the end of `Move`.

Comment: BviLLe_Kid: No error message.
KIKO Software & Mike McCaughan: your solution works! It is like a black magic. Thanks!

Comment: One follow up question. In the form there will be a get = "Post" so some calculations can be performed and the results will be shown in another html. The progress bar seems to block the subsequent action so no other webpages can be shown. How should I modify the code to get the work done?